# Find examples of two functions $g$ and $h$, not differing by a constant, such that $g'(x)=h'(x)=f(x)$ for all $x/=0$.

Tags: integration

Let $f(x)=2$ for $x<0$ and $f(x)=2x$ for $x\ge 0$. Find examples of two functions $g$ and $h$, not differing by a constant, such that $g'(x)=h'(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\ne 0$.

I thought there was a theorem corollary stating that any 2 antiderivatives of a function have to differ by a constant, but I don't know if that's the right answer???

Comment: The theorem only applies for functions defined on an interval. It's important that the domain is connected. Your hypothesis tells you that $g'(x)=h'(x)$ on $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$ which is not connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take $$g(x)=
\begin{cases}
2x & \text{if }x<0\\
x^2 & \text{if }x\ge 0
\end{cases}$$

and

$$h(x)=
\begin{cases}
2x +1& \text{if }x<0\\
x^2 & \text{if }x\ge 0
\end{cases}$$